# How to display words of different sizes, such as Office or function of Google Docs in Android

Tags: java, android, spannablestring, spannable, spanned

I try to do like the Office or Google Docs can enter a different word sizes this feature

Here is my code

```
input =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Input_EditText); 
input.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
{
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {   
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {    
    }
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
    {
        int index = input.getSelectionEnd();
        String nowstr;

        if(index==0)
        {
            //do nothing
        }
        else
        {
            nowstr = s.toString();
            char nowstr_array[] = nowstr.toCharArray();
            show_input = String.valueOf(nowstr_array[index-1]);

            SpannableStringBuilder  spann = new SpannableStringBuilder(show_input);
            AbsoluteSizeSpan word_size = new AbsoluteSizeSpan(40,true);
            spann.setSpan(word_size, 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            input.getText().insert(index, spann);
        }
    }
});
```

But this program will crash...

then,I try to do

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, spann, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//input.getText().insert(index, spann);
```

But doing so can be displayed...

That is why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            beforeText = s.toString() ;
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            int index = input.getSelectionEnd();
            String nowstr;

            if (index == 0) {
                // do nothing
            } else {
                if (beforeText.length() < s.toString().length()) {
                    nowstr = s.toString();
                    char nowstr_array[] = nowstr.toCharArray();
                    String show_input = String.valueOf(nowstr_array[index - 1]);

                    SpannableStringBuilder spann = new SpannableStringBuilder(
                            show_input);
                    AbsoluteSizeSpan word_size = new AbsoluteSizeSpan(40, true);
                    spann.setSpan(word_size, 0, 1,
                            Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    input.removeTextChangedListener(this) ;
                    input.getText().replace(index-1, index, spann) ;
                    input.addTextChangedListener(this) ;

                }
            }
        }

    });
```

beforeText is a  global variable

Answer (score 1):

because in method aftertextchanged you get the text and change text size,at last you insert the text into edittext,but the method will cause the textWatcher listener then will run aftertextchanged and in this method you also change the text so this is a dead loop,but if you use toast,it will not insert text then is will not cause the listener ,then it works :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94047/discussion-between-ljl5241861-and-ban-lin).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94104/discussion-on-answer-by-ljl5241861-how-to-display-words-of-different-sizes-such).

Answer (score 0):

First,the screen displays the following

[image]

Word will again appear small and big words, at this point is not what I want, I just want a big enough

Then I hit the delete key, the program will crash

Here is my code:

```
SpannableStringBuilder  spann = new SpannableStringBuilder(show_input);
spann.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(40,true), 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Integer.toString(index), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
input.removeTextChangedListener(this) ; 
input.getText().insert(index, spann);
input.addTextChangedListener(this) ;
```